# All files ending with a suffix without using negation

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match all files except those ending with .bmp.

Due to some constraints I can't use negation (?:, !:) and references (\1, ...).

I've made an expression and it works for most of the strings:

```
^\w+\.([^b].*|b|b[^m].*|bm|bm[^p].*|bmp.+)$
```

It matches everything that doesn't end with .bmp - including test.txt, test.bmp.txt, etc.
But unfourtanely, it does allow test.bi.bmp.

Any idea on how to improve the regex so it would just match files **not** ending with .bmp?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are those constraints?

Comment: There are other applications using the regex engine on the target machine and due to some reasons (which I'm not completely aware of, but I guess it might be related to performance, compatibility with something or speed) the regex engine is specifically compiled without it... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not:

```
^.*[^p]$|^.*[^m]p$|^.*[^b]mp$|^.*[^.]bmp$
```

?

http://regexr.com?31vg7

An [alternative](http://regexr.com?31vga) is `^.*([^p]|[^m]p|[^b]mp|[^.]bmp)$` (shorter).

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly (and much more elegant than what I wrote).

Though there is one last wrong filename that does pass the expression:
test..bmp

Comment: @Daniel: There's a bug in regexr with that regexp when text is on the last input line and it is followed by a blank line. I don't know why. Open a new line after that one and type anything else, and see.

Comment: Thanks. It completely solves my problem and I've learnt much from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
/^.+\.([^b][^.]*|b|b[^m][^.]*|bm|bm[^p][^.]*|bmp[^.]+)$/
```

just make sure that the dot before 'bmp' is the last dot

Comment: Doesn't [^.] just negates everything?

Comment: @Daniel: No, regex metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class.

Comment: I thought it only applied in ()... Good to know! thanks.

One last problem - test..bmp does pass.

Answer (score 0):

Not too elegant but works:

```
^.*([^b][^m][^p]|b[^m][^p]|[^b]m[^p]|[^b][^m]p|bm[^p]|[^b]mp)$
```

Comment: You are also assuming that extensions are always 3 letters long.

Comment: I don't, I just assume that .bmp is 3 letters long. Extensions having more than 3 characters will be matched too.

Comment: @Dmitry: for example test.notabmp? This should be matched by your regex, but I don't think it is.

Comment: test.bsp doesn't match also... maybe b[^m]p should be added to the OR clause?

Comment: Also it still matches anything.bmp... i think that is because * is greedy